# How do I fix Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use ddslick (http://designwithpc.com/plugins/ddslick)
My code:

```
<script>
$('#demoBasic').ddslick({
    var ddData = [{
        text: "Facebook",
        value: 1,
        selected: false,
        description: "Description with Facebook",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
    }, {
        text: "Twitter",
        value: 2,
        selected: false,
        description: "Description with Twitter",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
    }, {
        text: "LinkedIn",
        value: 3,
        selected: true,
        description: "Description with LinkedIn",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png"
    }, {
        text: "Foursquare",
        value: 4,
        selected: false,
        description: "Description with Foursquare",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png"
    }];
    data: ddData,
        width: 300,
        imagePosition: "left",
        selectText: "Select your favorite social network",
        onSelected: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
});
</script>
```

But i'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

How i can handle this problem?
I'm using JQuery 1.11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object definition starts wrong :

```
$('#demoBasic').ddslick({
    var ddData = [{
```

should read:

```
$('#demoBasic').ddslick({
    ddData : [{
```

(there are no uses for `var` inside an object definition)

also,
There is a semicolon in the middle of your object definition.

```
}];
```

should be :

```
}],
```

Last but not least, there is no need to define `ddata` like you do, since you can put it straight into `data`

```
<script>
$('#demoBasic').ddslick({
    data: [{
        text: "Facebook",
        value: 1,
        selected: false,
        description: "Description with Facebook",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
    }, {
        text: "Twitter",
        value: 2,
        selected: false,
        description: "Description with Twitter",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
    }, {
        text: "LinkedIn",
        value: 3,
        selected: true,
        description: "Description with LinkedIn",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png"
    }, {
        text: "Foursquare",
        value: 4,
        selected: false,
        description: "Description with Foursquare",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png"
    }],
    width: 300,
    imagePosition: "left",
    selectText: "Select your favorite social network",
    onSelected: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: not resolved.. JS Console tells that problem on this line: var ddData = [{

Comment: updated the answer. you shouldn't use `var` in any part of an object definition.

Comment: wait a minute... this makes no sense. hang on.

Comment: I'm got an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function) but fix it by replacing $ with JQuery. Thank you.